# How can I use the instance of Jetty container in the webapp on same container?

Tags: web-applications, jetty

We are developing application web server using Jetty. In the container, we made a few static instance that can use in the webapp loaded by same container. But we can't find the way to use the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are fighting classloader isolation here, instances of an object in one webapp are not allowed to be accessed by another webapp by design.

You should look into JNDI as a way of creating things that should be shared and linked up.  This is a common pattern for multiple applications to share a database pool for instance.